# Is it possible to hold a reference to a cloned html template element in javascript before adding it to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a template (later many more) where I would like to save a reference after cloning it:

```
var Atest;
....
let template= document.getElementById("template1");
let clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
Atest = clone; // Atest is defined global in the first line
document.getElementById("app").appendChild(clone);
```

This works perfectly fine. test has all the attributes of clone. But if I insert the clone to the DOM test looses all his children and many other informations:

```
document.getElementbyId("app").appendChild(clone);
```

The test variable should have the reference to the same document fragment (that stays in clone) which will be in the document. I do not want to make a copy of the element, because I want to access it later by the variable test to modify for example the value of a label ( in the same way as with getElementById() but without needing to attach an id)

Here an example:

HTML

```
<template id="template1">
    <label>Dimension-C</label>
    <input data-property="Position" type="text" value ="Pos1"/>
    <input data-property="Position" type="text" value ="Pos2"/>
    <input data-property="Position" type="text" value ="Pos3"/>1
</template>
```

JS:

```
let template= document.getElementById("template1");
let clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
Atest = clone; // Atest is defined global in the first line
document.getElementById("app").appendChild(clone);
```

Comment: May be the id of both the elements are same (for cloned one and the original element) thats why. Try to change the id of cloned element and then try.[ clone.id = "somethingElse"]

Comment: you are sure it does not ?. can you provide a simplyfied example ? thought you only could loos stuff which is dynamically added

Comment: clone.id is not defined, since clone is a document fragment at the time before adding @RK_15

Comment: I added a simplified version of my code for one template @user3732793

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content) property of a template element returns a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), which is basically a dummy container for DOM nodes. When inserting a `DocumentFragment` with [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), the children of the fragment are appended / moved to the new parent, that's why the fragment is empty after that operation.

If your template has only a single child, you can use `firstElementChild` on the fragment to get a reference to it:

```
var test;
let template = document.getElementById("template1");
let clone =template.content.cloneNode(true).firstElementChild;
test = clone;
```

Example:

```js
var test;
let template = document.getElementById("template1");
let clone =template.content.cloneNode(true).firstElementChild;
test = clone;

document.getElementById("app").appendChild(clone);
test.innerHTML += ' success';
```

```html
<template id="template1">
  <div>
  <span>test</span>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I either use a container object myself or I iterate through the document fragment if I have many children?

Comment: If the template has multiple children, you could probably do `test = Array.from(clone.children);` to get an array of the cloned nodes.